# How do I adjudicate the logic modality of certain death regarding the Fast Friends spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, character-death, duration

When I cast the *[Fast Friends](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fast-friends)* spell could I assign the afflicted target to a task that leads to a die roll that has a chance of 98% from death by falling damage without the spell ending immediately?

> If the activity would result in certain death for the creature, the
>   spell ends.

Does the task have to necessarily lead to death for the spell ending condition to take place?

How do I adjudicate death probabilities for the purpose of the duration of the *[Fast Friends](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fast-friends)* spell?

Comment: How/Why are you differentiating "death probabilities" from harm as a whole? I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. It's where to differentiate a Wis save to end it vs simply ending it because of...certain death?

Comment: @NautArch yes, harm in the spell's effect sets different conditions.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the effect of [Fast Friends](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fast-friends) is based on the target's point of view, as demonstrated by the wording (my emphasis)

> While the creature is charmed in this way, it undertakes to perform any services or activities you ask of it **in a friendly manner, to the best of its ability**.
>
> If the service or activity might cause harm to the creature, or **if it conflicts with the creature’s normal activities and desires**, the creature can make another Wisdom saving throw to try to end the effect.

The more discomfort or adversity that it perceives, the higher the likelihood that the effect ends (i.e. saving throw, advantage, or automatic).

IMO, a highly risk-averse creature might view 50% lethality as "certain" and break free, while an arrogant & reckless creature could view 90% odds of death as "might cause harm".

Comment: I'm still not certain your percentages are anything than purely your opinion (which you state, but also means your answer isn't supported), but I also updated the quotations with actual quotations emphasizing the points you made.

Comment: Thanks. The percentages are meant to be relative rather than absolute; the point is that the threshold for belief of "certain death" can vary widely..